# Ionic accordion is not resizing after click an item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an application developed in Ionic+Angular+Node. I use in there the accordion of Ionic, it is working fine but it is not resizing well, for example, if you click an item resizing remains exactly the same, but if you wait like 4 seconds, then it refresh OK and the same process occurs again in the show/hide item process.
Here is the Code:

```
<h4 class="subtitle" ng-click="accordionCtrl.toggle()">
  {{ accordionCtrl.page.title }}
  <i class="icon"
     ng-class="{ 'icon-arrow-dropdown': !accordionCtrl.show,
             'hm-open': accordionCtrl.show }"></i>
</h4>
<div class="content" ng-class="{ 'show': accordionCtrl.show }">
  <div class="description">
    <p ng-bind-html="accordionCtrl.page.content"></p>
    <p ng-repeat="page in accordionCtrl.page.children">
      <a ng-click="accordionCtrl.goTo('{{ ::page.view }}', { code: page.code })">{{ page.title }}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the js:

```
  (ng => {
  'use strict';

  class AccordionController {
    static get $inject () {
      return ['$state', '$IonicScrollDelegate'];
  }

  constructor ($state,$IonicScrollDelegate) {
    this._$state = $state;
    this._$IonicScrollDelegate = $IonicScrollDelegate;
  }

  toggle(){

    this.show = !this.show;

    this._$IonicScrollDelegate.resize();
  }
  goTo (state, options = {}) {
    this._$state.go(state, options);
    this._$IonicScrollDelegate.resize();
  }
}

  ng.module('halo')
    .component('accordion', {
      bindings: {
      page: '<',
  },
  templateUrl: 'templates/services/components/accordion.html',
  controller: AccordionController,
  controllerAs: 'accordionCtrl',
});
})(angular);
```

It supposed to work fine but it doesn't, please any suggestion!!??...